# Set sdcard "temporary write protect" bit on Linux

Tags: linux, mmc

I want to set the `TMP_WRITE_PROTECT` (temporary write protection) bit on my sdcard `/dev/mmcblk0`. I think this can be done by rewriting the CSD (card specific data) at `/sys/block/mmcblk0/device/csd`, but surely there's already a Linux tool to do all that bit-banging and recalculate the CRC?

I've found [mmc-utils](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/cjb/mmc-utils.git/), but it seems to use an incompatible interface:

```
# mmc extcsd read /dev/mmcblk0
ioctl: Connection timed out
Could not read EXT_CSD from /dev/mmcblk0
# mmc writeprotect get /dev/mmcblk0 
ioctl: Connection timed out
Could not read EXT_CSD from /dev/mmcblk0
```

And a Stack Overflow comment [mentioned a command line tool called sdtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242491/linux-device-node-for-sd-card-as-mmcblk-to-access-csd-register#comment41171006_26244786), but does not provide a URL...

Comment: sudo hdparm -r /dev/mmcblk0

Answer (score 4):

That mysterious `sdtool` you cannot find is hosted [here](https://github.com/BertoldVdb/sdtool), and you can indeed use it to enable temporary write protection on your card:

```
sudo umount /dev/mmcblk0p*
sudo sdtool /dev/mmcblk0 lock
sudo sdtool /dev/mmcblk0 reset
```

Similarly, `unlock` will remove the write protection.

A word of warning: my system is not able to recognize that the flag is set, so it's up to me to remount the filesystem as read-only. Mounting write-protected card as `rw` will silently allow writes which in reality won't take place, resulting in weird filesystem errors (which fortunately won't affect the SD card but still can hand up programs on your computer).

Comment: Does `sdtool` build for x86?