# How to write-protect sd card?

Tags: windows, sd-card

I have a 64gb SD card that I would like to mass distribute. It has a lot of software on it that I would like people to use, but I don't want them to be able to delete or change that data.

Just sliding the lock tab is not enough, many people can easily unlock it that way. Is there a way I can lock the card behind the scenes using software such as CMD? (I am using Windows 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical sliding tab on external storage is meant to protect against accidental deletion and malicious programs, not necessarily to secure data from a user.

After creating a partition on the external disk, and copying your data to it, you can set the drive to Read Only. This is more of a data integrity protection measure, and not necessarily a security measure, as the Read Only status could be removed by a knowledgeable user with admin rights on their computer. Access to this could be controlled in a controlled network environment.

1. Open PowerShell or CMD as Administrator
2. `diskpart` and press enter
3. `list disk` to see a list of physical disks
4. `select disk <#>` to select your disk drive, replace <#> with the number of your listed drive
5. `attributes disk` to see the state of the disk attributes
6. `attributes disk set readonly` to set the readonly flag
7. `attributes disk` again to confirm the flag was set.
8. Try to modify anything on disk, you will be prevented from doing so.

Here is a screenshot showing each step of the process, including clearing the read only flag at the end.

[image: diskpart]

Comment: Thanks. That appears to have my answer

Comment: You should really look at the WORM cards that Berard posted about in the other answer. That device solves this problem outright.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the thing you are looking for is a *WORM SD card* (Write Once Read Many).

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=worm+sd+card